# Ektron AD users: how to prevent certain ad users from logging in to workarea

Tags: active-directory, web-config, content-management-system, ektron

After the Ad integration of the ektron site how to to go about preventing certain active directory users from logging in to the work area?

Comment: What kind of interaction do you want them to have with the site? Do you want them to be able to browse and have a Community-like profile/information or do you want them to be contributing content?

Comment: This is going to be ektron 9.0 sp2 we want a small group to be able to login via work area  and update contents and for rest just be able to see the public site just like any no ad user who can't log in to the work area

Comment: Then the next question is: are you looking to have people log in to the site that are not in AD? The answer mentioning AD users as Membership users is the approach to look at. Once enabled, manually add the AD users you want Workarea access for to the Users, and the rest will go into Community Management > Memberships > Users. The catch with this method is non-AD users cannot log in to the site.

Comment: Yes Non AD user shouldn't able to log in to the workarea but only be able to visit public site

Answer (score 1):

**Quick and Simple answer:**
Once you start enabling AD Authentication, it becomes all-or-nothing. You cannot mix user authentication modes.

- CMS and Membership users can auth against Ektron.
- CMS users can auth against AD and Membership can auth against Ektron.
- CMS and Membership can auth against AD.
- **You cannot mix.**

If everyone is a CMS users, but not everyone should be doing "stuff" in the Workarea, you need to start managing User Groups and set permissions to restrict or allow activity in Workarea based on those groups. First thing: Deny everything to the Everyone group. Then start allowing activity to other groups.

**The Complex and Long explanation of user management in Ektron:**
With AD Authentication and Integration options in Ektron, you have a couple ways to manage user authentication, and how users exist in the system.

1. Standard AD Authentication - When enabled through the Web.config with ek_ADEnabled, and then through the Workarea > Settings > Configuration > Active Directory > Setup > "Enable Active Directory Authentication", AD users that login to the system will be handled as CMS users. Explanation about this: Just checking the radio button here and leaving the checkboxes unchecked will force CMS authentication against AD. This **does not** auto-add authenticated users, update properties, or force them into groups. It simply tests their username and pass against an LDAP query. Using just this method, you manually add the users you want to authenticate for CMS/Workarea access into the Users. Any users that are not added, will not be authenticated. Any other users would then use a membership username and pass to authenticate on the site and will not use AD.
2. Active Directory Itegration - Using the above method, you can enable "Integration." This updates the users properties and information from Active Directory when they log in successfully. With "Authentication" the user information, aside from UserName, Domain, and password, is managed in Ektron whereas "Integration" forces the rest of the user properties to match their AD values. Just enabling "Integration" still forces the users to be added manually to Users and any AD users who do not exists in Users cannot authenticate. Instead, they would need a non-ad Ektron Membership account to login.
3. Auto Add Options - With "Integration" enabled, you can enable the auto-creation of users in Ektron. If a user logs in to Ektron and successfully authenticates against Active Directory, but does not exist in Ektron yet, the user account will be created in Ektron in the Everyone group and will be granted those permissions. This means that all Active Directory users on your domain can authenticate as CMS users and get access. Enabling the "Auto Add User to Group" takes this an additional step and checks their AD User Groups against the Ektron groups. If one of the Ektron groups matches an AD group they are in, they will be added to the group in Ektron.
4. AD Memberships - If you only want a couple users in your Active Directory tree to have CMS access, and want the rest of your users to log in to the site using Active Directory credentials, you can enable AD Memberships by setting the "ek_LDAPMembershipUser" flag to "true" in the Web.config. This will force all membership users to authenticate against AD like CMS users do, though they will not have CMS access. With this enabled, however, standard user, non-AD user, authentication will not work. The users will be forced to authenticate against AD. The integration and auto-add options will also apply to membership users in this case and you can use the Login control, or the API to set the AutoAddType or force a login to only allow membership users.

Now, obviously if you choose not to enable AD Authentication, all users are authenticated against Ektron only. No communication to AD controllers is made. If you do not enable "ek_LDAPMembershipUser" all membership users are still authenticated only against Ektron. AD/LDAP authentication does not apply to them.

There is no mix-mode authentication in the system, however. You can have AD enabled with CMS users against AD and Membership against Ektron. Or, you can have AD enabled with CMS users against AD and Membership against AD as well. You cannot have CMS users against Ektron and Membership against AD, nor can you have some users as CMS or Membership against AD and other users against Ektron only. I do believe complex options like these will be available in a future release, but for now, once you start enabling AD Authentication, it becomes an all-or-nothing affair depending on where you set it.

And a very important point that should be made about User Groups: You can enable AD Authentication and manually manage User Groups in Ektron. The groups do not need to match AD User Groups. This means you can define your own groups in Ektron, force users to authenticate against Active Directory, and you can apply permissions to the Ektron Groups, independent of AD Group permissions.

I hope this helps shed some light on the user system.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on what version of Ektron you're on, but I believe this is an issue with the later versions of Ektron where they added the login logic directly to `cmslogin.aspx.cs` rather than using the `cms:Login` server control.

A workaround that I know of requires manually editing the login page (cmslogin.aspx) to prevent users from being automatically added as CMS "authors" using `EkEnumeration.AutoAddUserTypes.Author` and instead be added as membership users only.
You can also create your own login page to customize the logic and remove the stock login page; whatever you do, backup the stock page first :)

You may be able to play around with this piece:

```
m_eAutoAddType = EkEnumeration.AutoAddUserTypes.Member; // I added this.
if (bAutoLogin)
{
UserInfo = m_refUserApi.autologInUser(strUsername, strDomain, Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"], m_eAutoAddType);
}
else
{
UserInfo = m_refUserApi.logInUser(strUsername, strPassword, Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"], strDomain, strProtocol, m_eAutoAddType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will definitely try this

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly, one of the few user options still available in AD integration mode is the "lock user" checkbox on their profile.

Answer (score 0):

AD integration can be set up to affect either CMS users or Membership users.  CMS users have workarea access whereas Membership users do not.  It sounds like you have the wrong option setup.

In a typical Intranet scenario, all your users with AD integration tend to be Membership users.  This way they can create content on the site using the Community and Social features.

Your administrators will often have 2 accounts: their regular AD account and a CMS-only account that they can use to administer Ektron through the Workarea.

Comment: Thanks for the comment will double check ...during the integration it pulled all the users from ad :/